# Restricting python version or keywords in jedi

Tags: python, keyword, jedi, python-language-server

I want to use jedi to provide autocompletion for python editor.
I however do not want to support Python 3 yet, or certain other features like lambda functions. 
What is the place where I can configure this? 
Is jedi the right place or is the language server that uses Jedi the right place or is the parso the grammar parser the right place? 
Do any of these tools provide configuration options for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Jedi works with environments. These environments allow you to pick a specific Python version. If you just use Python 2, you will automatically get restricted by Jedi with the Python 2 syntax.

If you don't want to use lambda functions, just don't use them. There's no way how you can get rid of them in Jedi.